# Calling call() on a function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have code as follows:

```
def sum(a, b)
  a + b
end

puts sum.call 2, 3
```

I get an error like:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

How can I call a function?

*EDIT*

I want to have a function able to call other one with certain arguments. I've written the code like below but the same error is still displayed.

```
def sum(a, b)
  a + b
end

def kall(func, *args)
  send(func, *args)
end

puts kall(sum, 2, 3)
```

Comment: pass `:sum` (Symbol) instead of method `sum`:  `puts kall(:sum, 2, 3)`.

Comment: That works great.

Answer (score 5):

In order to invoke the function `sum`, just delete the `.call` call:

```
def sum(a, b)
  a + b
end

sum(1, 2)
# => 3
```

Other way to call the method is doing:

`send(:sum, 1, 2)`

Which invokes the method `sum` on the current context/object with the list of arguments (1, 2).

Comment: Use `public_send` instead of `send` in cases if the method is public.

Answer (score 2):

One more way to call a method is:

```
method(:sum).call(2, 3)
#=> 5
```

Comment: `call` is redundant :) `method(:sum).(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is not a function, it is a *method*. Methods *belong* to objects, they *aren't* objects. Ruby is an object-oriented language, which means you can only store objects in variables, only pass objects as arguments (with the slightly odd exception of blocks), only return objects from methods and only send messages to objects.

You cannot send a message to the `sum` method, because you can only send messages to objects, and methods aren't objects.

And even if it *were* possible to send messages to methods, there would still be an ambiguity in your code: Ruby allows you to leave out the argument list to a message send if you don't pass any arguments, therefore

```
sum
```

is a valid message send and is (somewhat) equivalent (modulo privacy) to

```
self.sum()
```

So, even *if* it were possible to send messages to methods, Ruby would *still* think that you try to send the `sum` message without an argument list.

So, since the problem is that we need an object, there are two things we can do. Firstly, we can use an object to begin with.

You used the term "function" in your question. Well, Ruby doesn't have functions, but it has something close to it: [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html)s. One solution would be to use a `Proc` instead of a method:

```
sum = -> (a, b) { a + b }
sum.(2, 3)
#=> 5
```

The other solution would be to obtain an object for the method. Ruby's Reflection System has a class called [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) which responds to [`call`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-call), instances of which are reflective proxies for methods. You can obtain a `Method` object by sending the [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) message to an object, e.g.:

```
sum = method(:sum)
sum.(2, 3)
#=> 5
```

Comment: Although true, please be aware that methods _are_ objects in Ruby. There is a class `Method` that represents a method :)

Comment: No, they are not. You *can* obtain a reflective *proxy* object for a method, but it is just that: a *proxy*. I have learned that the hard way when I tried to store additional metadata information directly inside a method. Depending on how you obtain the `Method` object, you may or may not get multiple different proxy objects for the same method, and obviously only one of those will have the data that you stored in it. I do show in the last paragraph how to obtain a `Method` proxy object for a method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do .call or anything like that. **If the function has no parameters, simply just type the name of the function. And if the function does have parameters, just do `myFunction(param1, param2)`.**

```rb
def hello
  puts 'Hello, World!'
end

def output(string)
  puts string
end


# Both of these do the same thing:
hello
hello()


# Doing that with stdout won't work though. It expects one argument, string
output('You can do it with parenthesis')
output 'You can also do it without'
```